# Convert unconventional string to mysql datetime in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to convert a field that represents a date-time but is currently a VARCHAR to a DATETIME field.
Currently the representation looks like: 'Sun May 20 01:04:39 +0000 2012'
I want to do this operation in a query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use **[`STR_TO_DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)**

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('Sun May 20 01:04:39 +0000 2012', '%a %M %d %H:%i:%S +0000 %Y')
```

- [**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/3321)
- [**Date Format**](http://davidwalsh.name/format-date-mysql-date_format)

Comment: Great, I was pretty close. Was missing the %a (which I assume represents a word?)

Comment: `%a` is *Abbreviated weekday name*

Comment: Cool. The %x%x%x%x%x edit you made makes the year come out wrong

Comment: @Noam forgot to remove it. i was experimenting..hehe

Comment: Also I think the +0000 represents the Time Zone. Can I save that also?

Comment: @Noam this one is better `%a %M %d %H:%i:%S %x%x %Y` but i can't find any equivalent for timezone.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18956/discussion-between-noam-and-john-woo)

Answer (score 0):

Use the [DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) function.

This does the job and can be used inside queries.

Comment: DATE('Sun May 20 01:04:39 +0000 2012') return NULL